# WPF Disable Autorun for Removable Media in Windows 7

Tags: wpf, windows-7

I am developing a wpf program which handle the removable media in windows 7 32bit. What I want to do is while my application is running, I want to disable the autorun popup dialog which come out when the thumb-drive plug in. Is there a possible way to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really possible even in native code. In theory you want to implement and register `IQueryCancelAutoPlay` but this is not very reliable.

Comment: "Not very reliable" is a bit vague, could you tell some cases where it doesn't work as expected? So far i only read that it only works if the window is in the foregound.

Comment: I'd wish that I knew, but this is just based on observation of hundreds of machines. On a significant number of them, I've seen it fail, but we have never been able to determine the precise cause.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to set the registry key is the only solution I know. It's HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer\NoDriveTypeAutorun.

Take a look at this [MS-Support-Page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715/en-us) for the values you can set.